# Random number generator android

Tags: android, random

**ActivityMain.java**

```
package com.abhinav.random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int count=0;
public int rand_num;
public int n;
EditText edt_rand;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rand_num=(int)(Math.random()*100);
    edt_rand=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_rand);
    n = Integer.parseInt(edt_rand.toString());
}

public void onclick(View v){
        if(count!=5){
            if(n>rand_num){
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,"Your number is greater", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            if(n<rand_num){
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,"Your number is greater", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            else{
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Task complete")
                .setMessage("You Win")
                .setNeutralButton("Close", new                              DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                })
                .show();
            }
        }
        else{
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("No Chances Left")
            .setMessage("You Lose")
            .setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()       {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            })
            .show();
        }

}

}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
enter code here
 <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edt_rand"
    android:hint="@string/number"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    ></EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_rand"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rand"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rand"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/click" 
    android:onClick="onclick"/>
```

Whats wrong with the above code?

Comment: What is that you are actually looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is below line in onCreate() method;

```
n = Integer.parseInt(edt_rand.toString());
```

You are actually initializing an edittext and directly fetching a value from it. In such the case the value of **n** will be null or ""

modify your code like below,

```
 public void onclick(View v){
         n = Integer.parseInt(edt_rand.getText().toString());  // write this line here
 ...
 }
```

Comment: You don't even know what is his problem. Your code it self will generate Number Format exception. as you can't convert edittext to Integer.

Comment: `edt_rand.toString()` should be `edt_rand.getText().toString()` `View.toString` return String representation of View which is not valid to convert to Integer

Comment: @AbhinavPandey, did you changed `edt_rand.toString()` to `edt_rand.getText().toString()` ?

Comment: @AbhinavPandey, you welcome, you may accept my answer by ticking the tick mark besides my answer.

Answer (score 0):

i have one function for generate random number.

```
    public String getDynamic()
    {
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(99 - 10) + 10;
    String privateString = String.valueOf(i1) ;
    return privateString;

    }
```